# Regular expression limit length of character while not matching last character of string

Tags: regex

I'm working on a new regex to prepare for a host-name on a virtual machine, however, I'm running into issue on how to limit character length of 24 while making sure the last character is not a dot or a minus. (the first character must be an alpha character)

I have gotten as far as making sure the first character is an alpha.  The second group of characters are 23 in length with `[a-zA-z0-9]` including the dot and minus. I've tried the negative look-behind `.+(?<!-|\.)$` in addition but does not work.

`^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9-.]{0,23}`

I expect the output of a123456789012345678911234 to be correct already.
I expect this output should be incorrect a12345678901234567891123-

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-.]{0,22}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$`?

Comment: why doesn't ^a[a-zA-Z0-9]{23} work? If you don't want to match "." or "-" then don't include them in the expression.

Comment: @Ghoti thanks for the comment.  "." or "-" characters are okay as long as it's not the last character in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{0,22}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KAPBwe/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z0-9.-%5D%7B0%2C22%7D%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D)%3F%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{0,22}[a-zA-Z0-9])?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{0,22}` - 0 to 22 letters, digits, `.` or `-` chars
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]`  - a letter or digit
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

In order to limit the number of characters, the expression must be enclosed in ^ and $ denoting the beginning and the end.

```
     ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.-]{0,22}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[] defines one character from those in parentheses
{a, b} defines the number of occurrences of the preceding character from 0 to 22 in the example
a total limit of 2 to 24 characters

This can be saved shorter but in this way it is the easiest to understand.